# How to unpivot a data using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unpivot

I have a table as below,

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 12,45 |
| Kenny | 1,4,6 |
| Jude | 1,4,5,7 |
| Benji | 15,48 |

Need it like as below

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | 12 |
| Tom | 45 |
| Kenny | 1 |
| Kenny | 4 |
| Kenny | 6 |
| Jude | 1 |
| Jude | 4 |
| Jude | 5 |
| Jude | 7 |

I have tried using the [`FILTER`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function, however it is not providing what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 365. assuming a range of `A1:B4` (change as required within the formula):

`=LET(ζ,A1:B4,κ,INDEX(ζ,,1),λ,INDEX(ζ,,2),α,"<a><b>",β,"</b><b>",γ,"</b></a>",δ,"//b",ξ,FILTERXML(α&TEXTJOIN(β,,SUBSTITUTE(λ,",",β))&γ,δ),IF(SEQUENCE(,2,0),ξ,INDEX(FILTERXML(α&CONCAT(REPT(κ&β,1+LEN(λ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(λ,",",""))))&γ,δ),SEQUENCE(COUNT(ξ)))))`

It is assumed that there are no names in column A with a corresponding blank in column B.

Comment: hey thanks for the solution, how may i upvote

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps as a new member you don't yet have the privilege to upvote?